# What is `x/24x $esp` mean?

Tags: assembly, memory, operating-system, stack, xv6

I'm running `xv6` - operating system made from MIT. I'm running gdb to check the stack pointer(?). And I'm running `gdb` to see the value of stack pointer registers.

My professor said "Let's look at the stack" then typed `x/24x $esp`.

**Question:** What is `x`, `/`, `24`, `$esp`??? $esp is just a stack pointer showing the current address of the stack register?

The output I got is:

```
(gdb) x/24x $esp
0x7bdc: 0x00007db4  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7bec: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7bfc: 0x00007c4d  0x8ec031fa  0x8ec08ed8  0xa864e4d0
0x7c0c: 0xb0fa7502  0xe464e6d1  0x7502a864  0xe6dfb0fa
0x7c1c: 0x16010f60  0x200f7c78  0xc88366c0  0xc0220f01
0x7c2c: 0x087c31ea  0x10b86600  0x8ed88e00  0x66d08ec0
```

I found some reference from Google:

> x/6x $esp in order to see what int put on the stack.

```
(gdb) x/6x $esp
0x7bdc: 0x00007db4  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7bec: 0x00000000  0x00000000
```

which doesn't make sense to me.

P.S I need to find the start of the stack and the items on the stack at this point. (once I understand this command!)

Reference: https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2012/lec/l-interrupt.html

Comment: It seems to be some kind of personal notation used by your prof. So better ask him.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation?  What program did your professor type this into?

Comment: Uhm I thought it's like basic terminal command

Comment: Reference: https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2012/lec/l-interrupt.html

Comment: `x` command means examine memory. `/24x` mean to print out the next 24 values in HEX notation.. By default for general memory queries the default is to display  DWORDS (32-bit values). The address to start displaying at is specified as `$esp`. So the command you have displays 24 DWORD values in HEX starting at the address in the ESP register. (in GDB registers need to have a `$` prepended to them). You can get help on instructions via `help` at GDB command line. `help x` would tell you how the `x` command works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a `gdb` command which says to display (e**x**amine) 24 words at the top of the stack in hex.

One would do that to see the current function's return address, stack frame pointer, function parameters, and local variables.

---

Oh, I see:  You might not be familiar with stacks.

On 99% of all processors, stacks grow up (toward lower-numbered memory), the reverse of an array.  See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Structure) which helpfully contains this diagram:
[image]

This is worth spending a few hours reading and understanding.  Stacks are *extremely* important in computing.

Comment: Actually by default when no type information is given (or available), on x86 GDB defaults to displaying DWORDs (32-bit values), not 16-bit WORDs

Comment: @MichaelPetch:  `WORD` and `DWORD` are Microsoft-specific concepts.  I rarely speak *Microsoft*.  A computer word is specified by the architecture.  On a 32-bit machine, it is 32 bits.  On a 64-bit machine, a word is 64 bits.

Comment: So it shows Locals of DrawLine, Return Address, Parameters for Drawline, ... from stack's top Order???

Comment: DWORD isn't just isn't a Microsoftism. I happened to specify there size in parentheses. You answer suggests then that if you were to debug a 64-bit program with GDB that your definition of WORD would be displayed (64-bit values by your definition). Even in x86-64 GDB defaults to 32-bit DWORD values for general memory display unless you override it. GDB's defaults for memory display on x86 platforms do not default based on architecture word size.

Comment: @JohnBaek:  Yes.  It requires some research to determine which is what, but the layout *pattern* is very standard.

Comment: Cool thanks!. So to find the start of the stack, I need to find the length of the stack. And to find the items on the stack, I need to do some research on xv6's stack on assembly code. Cool

Comment: @JohnBaek:  Rarely do you need to find the length of the stack.  A chief feature of stacks is that they grow as needed.  Like a stack of papers on a desk, one doesn't care much about how many there are:  only that the few items on the top is what you initially work with.  Once those are cleared away, then the layer below becomes workable.

Comment: @MichaelPetch:  I am a bit confused, but I think you are conflating `WORD` with *word*.  The later means [*a natural unit of data*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)) and has no absolute size except on a specific CPU architecture.

Comment: @JohnBaek:  Usually you never need to find the start of the stack.  However, the stack pointer always points to the *end* of the stack, which is popularly called the *top of stack*.  Stacks are organized backwards in memory.

Comment: Uhm but professor wants me to find the start of the stack. I guess this is challenging question. I will do more research on that

Comment: I wouldn't be making the comment if I already knew that the architectural word size is not how GDB defaults display data at specified memory locations. GDB on x86/x86-64 targets does NOT use architectural word size for display data in memory (unless overridden).

Comment: Interesting. :)

Comment: @JohnBaek:  I wonder if by `start` the professor means `top`?

Comment: professor said "You have to figure out where the stack pointer is initialized."

Comment: I think I can find it on the bootloader assembly file

Comment: Actually `gdb` defaults to the size previously used if you don't specify one. As such `x/24x` might even give you bytes. Better specify size.

Comment: OP:"stack" is ordinary memory, like any other, the "stack" magic is created by reserving some memory area for this purpose, and set `esp` to point to the end of such area, and let the specialized instructions, which implicitly work with `esp` pointer (`push/pop/call/ret/leave/...`) to use that reserved area. By the `x.. $esp` gdb command the professor did check content of that memory area right at the "top of stack" and further, i.e. in your Q the first dword `0x00007db4` would be the value loaded into `eax` by `pop eax`. And after `pop` the `esp` would be `+= 4`, pointing at `0x7BE0` address.

Comment: @JohnBaek if you would do instead `push dword 0x12345678`, the `esp -= 4` would be done first (pointing now to `0x7BD8` address) and the four bytes `78 56 34 12` (little-endian encoding of 32bit value) written there, so `x/24x $esp` after such push would display memory from -4B ahead of your example, and starting with `0x12345678` dword, then the remaining memory having the same content as in your question (`0x00007db4` `0x00000000` ...)

Comment: @wallyk no it doesn't. gdb defaults to the most recently used size. Admittedly, at startup that might be `word`. But if you examined something with a different size previously, you will get that size again.

Comment: I KNOW you are referring to ARCHITECTURAL WORD. GDB doesn't default to ARCHITECTURAL WORD for displaying memory (as the default) If you believe GDB is using ARCHITECTURAL WORD then compile a simple x86-64 program (assume your GDB is default settings) and do `x/24x $rsp`. If GDB were using ARCHITECTURAL WORD it would display 24 64-bit values (since ARCHITECTURAL WORD = 64-bits). GDB doesn't by default. It displays a 32-bit DWORDs. That is its default when displaying arbitrary memory that has no type info or you don't override it with something like `x/24gx $rsp` where `g` displays 64-bit values

Comment: As jester correctly points out it can be overridden by previous actions as well. But by default state is not to display based on ARCHITECTUAL WORD.